# How to change a jquery mobile radio button group with javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile, I want to change a radio group with javascript code. I have this:

```
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                    <legend>Co-op Department:</legend>
                        <input name="coopdepartment" id="artssciRB" value="Arts & Science" checked="checked" type="radio">
                        <label for="artssciRB">Arts & Science</label>
                        <input name="coopdepartment" id="managementRB" value="Management" type="radio">
                        <label for="managementRB">Management</label>
                        <input name="coopdepartment" id="idsRB" value="IDS" type="radio">
                        <label for="idsRB">IDS</label>
                </fieldset>
```

JS

```
var all = $("#profile-edit-form").find("input");
all.removeAttr("checked");
$("#profile-edit-form").find("input[value="+user['department_name']+"]").attr( "checked", "checked" );
all.checkboxradio( "refresh" );
```

but its not working... Does anyone know what is wrong? It is putting a checked attribute on the input tag though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.attr()` refers to the HTML attribute in the actual markup. What you want to work with is not the HTML attribute but the DOM property of the element. You want `.prop('checked')` for this rather than `.attr('checked')`.

Answer (score 1):

Current checkbox state is not its `attr`, it's a `prop`.

```
all.prop("checked", false);
```

should work.